# How to generate a random number between 1 and 75 repeating every 10 seconds in Swift

Tags: swift

I have the following code in Swift trying to get a simple random number generator as a simulator for a game.

```
var randomNumber = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(74) + 1)

    label.text = "\(randomNumber)"

}
```

I'm new to programming Swift but I know to use `timer()` and `import Foundation` to use the timer function but I'm not sure how to implement and make it so a new number appears in the label every 10 seconds. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Simply get the number in the timer callback. But you don't want duplicates so you can't simply generate a random number between 1 and 75 each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Timer` with an interval of `10` seconds to pull a new number from an array of `numbers`.  Remove the number from the array so that you don't call the same number twice.  When the `stop` button is pressed, or you are out of numbers call `invalidate` on the `timer` to stop it.

```
class BingoCaller: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var numbers = Array(1...75)
    let letters = ["B", "I", "N", "G", "O"]
    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 10, repeats: true) { timer in
            let index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.numbers.count)))
            let number = self.numbers.remove(at: index)
            self.label.text = "\(self.letters[(number - 1) / 15])-\(number)"
            if self.numbers.isEmpty {
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stop(_ button: UIButton) {
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Suggestions for next steps:

1. Add the numbers that have been pulled to a second array.  Use that array to populate a tableView so that Gran is able to review the numbers when someone calls "Bingo!".
2. Use `AVSpeechSynthesizer` to have the iPhone actually speak the numbers.
3. Add a reset button to start a new game.  Initialize the `numbers` to `Array(1...75)`, the `calledNumbers` to `[]` and start again.  It's a good idea to move the `Timer` loop to its own function so that it can be called from a `start` button.

Comment: What's the point of `letters`? Playing Bingo with actual letters?

Comment: In Bingo, the numbers are called with a letter "B-7", "O-73", "I-16" so that the number is easier to find on the card.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a helper array, that would let you check if that number was already returned:

```
var array = [Int]()
var timer: Timer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 10, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.timerFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func timerFunction(){
    var n = arc4random_uniform(75) + 1
    while array.contains(Int(n)){
        n = arc4random_uniform(75) + 1
    }
    array.append(Int(n))
    label.text = String(n)
    if array.count == 75{
        timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

This way you are sure that the timer is invalidated when all the numbers have already been used and also avoid index-removal errors.

Comment: This is very inefficient. Look at how most card games are implemented. It's the same. Fill an array with the numbers. Shuffle the array. Then access each element one-by-one as the timer goes off.